# Chrome loading IE only stylesheet

Tags: google-chrome, stylesheet

A stylesheet being loaded inside an IE conditional tag is being loaded in Google Chrome version 11.0.696.65. The IE only rules are throwing off our layout in Chrome.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link href="/Content/site.ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I've checked the code character for character and it looks fine to me. Is anyone else experiencing this? Is this a Chrome bug or some misguided feature?

Edit: Chrome is fine. We have a custom theme switcher which was erroneously loading a different copy of the site.ie.css from a theme's folder.

Comment: I can't reproduce this using 11.0.696.71.

Comment: I experienced this bug in Chrome 18.  Lg102's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome is fine. We have a custom theme switcher built which was erroneously loading a different copy of the site.ie.css from a theme's folder.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<!--[if gte IE 5]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

It will target every internet explorer version above ie5, which should be the same as all ie versions. I have never had problems with conditional comments, not in Chrome or any other browser, but i always target only specific browser versions.

Answer (score 0):

Im using the same version works for me on [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BbW3s/). I would try reinstalling Chrome?

Comment: I tried the same thing and got the same results. I'm going through the rest of the html to see what's causing it now. Thanks.